# MVC Razor, LINQ into J-Query?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the best way to pass a LINQ value into J-Query???... How would I go about this?
When the Update link is clicked, it checks the web Grid to see if it is the same on TrailerNumber and CarrierName. If the inputs are the same in both fields as already existing, then allows you to move the data to the current row. (avoid duplication)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        Checks to see is the inputs already exist in TrailerNumber and CarrierName as the same.
         LINQ (Controller): 
         bool AlreadyInTable = entities.LocationDataMasters.Any(t => t.TrailerNumber == customer.TrailerNumber && t.CarrierName == customer.CarrierName);

   //Update event handler.
   $("body").on("click", "#webGrid TBODY .Update", function () {

var row = $(this).closest("tr");
$("td", row).each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
        var span = $(this).find(".label");
        var input = $(this).find(".text");
        span.html(input.val());
        span.show();
        input.hide();
    }
});

row.find(".Edit").show();
row.find(".Cancel").hide();
row.find(".Clear").show();
$(this).hide();

var customer = {};
customer.LocationID = row.find(".LocationID").find(".label").html();
customer.UserName = row.find(".UserName").find(".label").html();
customer.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
customer.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
customer.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
customer.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
customer.LoadCommodityStatus = row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
customer.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
customer.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/UpdateCustomer",
    data: '{customer:' + JSON.stringify(customer) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
}) //setInterval('location.reload()', 777);

/*************************** Added to Find Duplicates ******************************/
/***********************************************************************************/
/***********************************************************************************/

//(1)Finds the Current Row selected with Edit Link: 
var CurrentLocationID = $(this).closest("tr").find('#LocationIDLbl').text();
var CurrentLocation = $(this).closest('tr').find("#LocationLbl").text();
var CurrentSection = $(this).closest('tr').find("#SectionLbl").text();
var CurrentTrailerNumber = $(this).closest('tr').find("#TrailerNumberLbl").text();
var CurrentTrailerNumberVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("#TrailerNumber").val();
var CurrentCarrrierNameLbl = $(this).closest('tr').find("#CarrierNameLbl").text();
var CurrentCarrrierName = $(this).closest('tr').find("#CarrierName").val();
var CurrLocationID = $(this).closest('tr').find("#LocationID").val();
var CurrentIDTrailerCarrier = 'Current Row Location, LocationID: ' + CurrentLocationID + ' Location: ' + CurrentLocation + ' Section: ' + CurrentSection + ' TrailerNumber: ' + CurrentTrailerNumber + ' CarrierName: ' + CurrentCarrrierName;
var TrailerNumberRows = $('#webGrid tr').find("#TrailerNumber").val();

//Identify the current row data to find duplicates against. 
///   alert("CurrentIDTrailerCarrier: " + CurrentIDTrailerCarrier);

// $('#webGrid TR').each(function (row, x) {

//=========== This decision is what determines to check for duplicates. ==============
//Loop through Rows that contain the same Trailer Number and Count Rows: 
var TrailerNumberContainsCount = $("#webGrid tr > td #TrailerNumberLbl:contains('" + CurrentTrailerNumber + "')").parent().length;
var CarrierNameContainsCount = $("#webGrid tr > td.CarrierName:contains('" + CurrentCarrrierNameLbl + "')").parent().length;

///  alert("TrailerNumberContainsCount: " + TrailerNumberContainsCount + " CarrierNameContainsCount: " + CarrierNameContainsCount);

**if (TrailerNumberContainsCount > 1 && $("#webGrid tr > td #TrailerNumberLbl:contains('" + CurrentTrailerNumber + "')") && $("#webGrid tr > td.CarrierName:contains('" + CurrentCarrrierNameLbl + "')") && CarrierNameContainsCount > 1 ) {**

    /****************************************************************/
    /************** Find Duplicates Get the LocationID **************/
    /****************************************************************/

    //Hide rows on TrailerNumber & CarrierName that don't match.
    $("#webGrid tr > td #TrailerNumberLbl:not(:contains('" + CurrentTrailerNumber + "'))").filter(':visible').parents().closest('TR').hide();
    $("#webGrid tr > td #CarrierNameLbl:not(:contains('" + CurrentCarrrierNameLbl + "'))").filter(':visible').parent().closest('TR').hide(); //Hide Rows that don't contain value.
    //Take out the ID that is on the current row to show the duplicate ID only. 
    var DuplicateID = $('#webGrid tr').filter(':visible').find("#LocationIDLbl:not(:contains('" + CurrentLocationID + "'))").text();
    DuplicatesVisibleID = DuplicateID;


    //Call the DuplicateID Row to be colored Yellow where the duplicate exists:
    $("#webGrid tr #LocationIDLbl:contains('" + DuplicatesVisibleID + "')").closest('tr').filter(':visible').attr('style', 'background-color:#FFFF00;');
    $('#webGrid tr:first').parent().show(); //Always show the header.

    /********************************************************/
    /****************** Start Selection *********************/
    /********************************************************/
    ///$('.SelectedMoveToChecked').attr('disabled', true);

    //Allow only one selection of the row to be checked on a checkbox.
    $('.SelectedMoveToChecked').click('td', function () {
        $(".SelectedMoveIsChecked").not(this).prop('checked', false);
        $(".SelectedMoveToChecked").not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });


    //$(this).closest('tr').find('.RowLocationDupDropDownList').removeAttr('disabled');
    $(".SelectedMoveIsChecked").filter(':visible').hide();
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".SelectedMoveToChecked").show();


    //$('.RowLocationDupDropDownList').hide();

    //Gather the data from the row that has the LocationID that is the Duplicate.
    var DupRow = $("#webGrid tr #LocationIDLbl:contains('" + DuplicatesVisibleID + "')").closest('tr').filter(':visible');
    var DupLocation = DupRow.find('#LocationLbl').text();
    var DupSection = DupRow.find('#SectionLbl').text();
    var DupTrailerNumber = DupRow.find('#TrailerNumberLbl').text();
    var DupCarrierName = DupRow.find('#CarrierNameLbl').text();
    var DupLoadCommodityStatus = DupRow.find('#LoadCommodityStatusLbl').text();
    var DupDateLoaded = DupRow.find('#DateLoadedLbl').text();
    var DupUserName = DupRow.find('#UserNameLbl').text();
    var DupPlantLocation = DupRow.find('#PlantLocationLbl').text();
    /// alert("DupLocationID: " + DuplicatesVisibleID + " DupLocation: " + DupLocation + " DupSection: " + DupSection + " DupTrailerNumber: " + DupTrailerNumber + " DupCarrierName: " + DupCarrierName);
    $(".RowLocationDupDropDownList").hide();
    // var $actualRow = $(row);

    let text = DupSection + ' ' + DupLocation + ' ' + DuplicatesVisibleID;
    $("select option").filter(function () {
        //may want to use $.trim in here
        return $(this).text() == text;
    }).prop('selected', true);


    $(".SelectedMoveToChecked").change(function () {
        /// e.preventDefault();
        //$('select.RowLocationDupDropDownList').each(function () {
        if ($("select.SelectedMoveToChecked").closest('checked', true)) {
            $(this).closest("tr").find('.RowLocationDupDropDownList').attr('disabled', true).show();
        }
        if ($('select.SelectedMoveToChecked').closest('checked', false)) {
            $('.SelectedMoveToChecked').closest('checked', false).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        $('select.RowLocationDupDropDownList').children("option:selected").text(DupSection + ' ' + DupLocation + ' ' + DuplicatesVisibleID);

        /**********************************************************/
        /********** Start Confirmation Dialogue Options ***********/
        /**********************************************************/

        if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() != '') {

            function DuplicateMoveConfirm() {
                var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
                confirm_value.type = "hidden";
                confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
                var ConfirmStr = "Are you sure, you want to move this? \n" + " TrailerNumber: " + DupTrailerNumber + " CarrierName: " + DupCarrierName + " \n\n " + " From Duplicate Row: \n"
                    + " Section: " + DupSection + " Location:" + DupLocation + " Row ID:" + DuplicatesVisibleID + " \n\n ";
                if (confirm("Confirm Move Aready Existing To Current Row! " + ConfirmStr + "To Current Row: \n" + " Section: " + CurrentSection + " Location: " + CurrentLocation + " Row ID: " + CurrentLocationID + "?")) {
                    confirm_value.value = "Yes";
                    //Trigger/Handler from Drop-Down Box Change.
                    $("body").on("change", ".SelectedMoveToChecked", function () {
                        // $("body").on("change", "#TrailerNumber", function (e) {
                        // e.preventDefault();

                        ///  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                        var row = $("#webGrid tr #LocationIDLbl:contains('" + DuplicatesVisibleID + "')").closest('tr').filter(':visible'); //Focus on the other row, not current row. 
                        $("webGrid td", row).each(function () {
                            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                                span.html(input.val());
                            }
                        });

                        //Tell the row change to be where ID exists by ID Number (RowLocationIDNum) 9 Items where data comes from.
                        var ToRow = {};
                        // ToRow.LocationID = RowLocationIDNum;
                        ToRow.LocationID = CurrentLocationID;
                        //ToRow.LocationID = DuplicatesVisibleID;
                        ToRow.UserName = row.find(".UserName").find(".label").html();
                        ToRow.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
                        ToRow.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
                        ToRow.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
                        ToRow.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
                        ToRow.LoadCommodityStatus = row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
                        ToRow.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
                        ToRow.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();

                        // setInterval('location.reload()', 777);
                        //Set the Clear Event to clear the initial rows. 
                        /// var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                        var row = $("#webGrid tr #LocationIDLbl:contains('" + DuplicatesVisibleID + "')").closest('tr').filter(':visible'); //Focus on the other row, not current row. 
                        $("td", row).each(function () {
                            if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                                var span = $(this).find(".label");
                                var input = $(this).find(".text");
                                $(this).find(".text").show();
                                $(this).find(".label").hide();
                                span.html(input.val(null));
                                span.show();
                                input.hide();
                            }
                        })
                        row.find(".Cancel").show();
                        row.find(".Clear").show();
                        row.find(".Edit").show();
                        $(this).hide();
                        var clear = {};

                        //Clear Duplicate Row After Moving the Data to the Current Row. 
                        // clear.LocationID = DuplicatesVisibleID;
                        clear.LocationID = row.find(".LocationID").find(".label").html();
                        clear.UserName = row.find(".UserName").find(".label").html();
                        clear.Location = row.find(".Location").find(".label").html();
                        clear.Section = row.find(".Section").find(".label").html();
                        clear.TrailerNumber = row.find(".TrailerNumber").find(".label").html();
                        clear.CarrierName = row.find(".CarrierName").find(".label").html();
                        clear.LoadCommodityStatus = row.find(".LoadCommodityStatus").find(".label").html();
                        clear.DateLoaded = row.find(".DateLoaded").find(".label").html();
                        clear.PlantLocation = row.find(".PlantLocation").find(".label").html();


                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Home/UpdateRowExchange",
                            data: '{ToRow:' + JSON.stringify(ToRow) + '}',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function () {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "/Home/ClearCustomer",
                                    data: '{clear:' + JSON.stringify(clear) + '}',
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                })
                            }
                        })
                        setInterval('location.reload()', 777);
                    })
                }
                else {
                    confirm_value.value = "Cancel";
                    setInterval('location.reload()', 777);
                }
                document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
            }
            DuplicateMoveConfirm();
        }
    });
}
```

});

//It finds when both TrailerNumber and CarrierName, but also finds when just TrailerNumber, even though CarrierName is not the same.
[image]

Comment: Does your `<table>` include *all* the entries from `entities.LocationDataMasters`?  Does your `<table>` include *any* form of paging?  Where some rows might be hidden?  If yes (all records) and no (no hidden rows) then you can use `.filter()` on the `tr` rows to find any that match.   If no (not all records)  or yes (some paging) then make an ajax call to your server to check across all entities.

Comment: Yes, that is what this J-Query code does, it filters out all the rows that don't match, but my question is the decision to find out if there is a match:  **if (TrailerNumberContainsCount > 1 && $("#webGrid tr > td #TrailerNumberLbl:contains('" + CurrentTrailerNumber + "')") && $("#webGrid tr > td.CarrierName:contains('" + CurrentCarrrierNameLbl + "')") && CarrierNameContainsCount > 1 ) {**  Right now it finds a match, but the problem is that only if the TrailerNumber exists, needs to be both TrailerNumber and CarrrierName.

Comment: LINQ lets me know positively if there is a match (True/False) would be a great option, just don't know how to get the value into J-Query.